# Wordpress WP-PageNavi Not working with specific category post on homepage

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using the following code to display recent posts from a specific category on the homepage of my WordPress website.

```
<div class="frontleft">
  <div id="four-columns" class="grid-container" style="display:block;">
    <?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=3&posts_per_page=24' ); ?>
    <ul class="rig columns-4">
      <?php while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
      <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
        </a>
        <h3>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h3>
      </li>
      <?php endwhile; ?> 
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); } else { ?>
    <?php } ?> 
  </div>
</div>
```

**Issue**: `WP-pageNavi` plugin isn't working correctly.

**Note:** I'm able to open `website.com/page/2` without having any issues. But the post list is precisely the same on each page.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would just use different Page Templates for homepage and other pages.
It's hard to debug a plugin that we aren't using.

There is a function in Wordpress is_page() where you can input the name of the page in the para. Throwing that in an if statement is also another way to separate the posts.

There are a ton of ways to achieve what your looking for without the use of a plugin.